# F value of zero in ANOVA

Tags: anova

I've read that it shouldn't be possible to get a F value equal to zero, but my result of a mixed ANOVA was:

F(1, 200)= .000, p = .955, observed power =.050

Box and Levene are not significant.

Can someone explain how this is possible? What am I missing?

Grateful for any help, thanks!

Comment: Perhaps there is something about your data that is causing the very small value of F. Are all your observations independent?

Comment: We assessed a value for each participant at baseline and then again after 2 weeks. I checked the data and each subject was only included once. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Did you use a statistical analysis that takes into account that you have repeated measures?  If not, the variance due to participants goes into the error variance.  It may be that the variance between participants is much greater than the variance due to your treatment, resulting in a small F.

Comment: Are you sure you have reported all statistics correctly?  The problem is that only an $F$ statistic of $0.0032$ would produce a p-value of $0.955$ with 1 and 200 degrees of freedom.

Comment: I did a mixed repeated measures test on SPSS testing for time, group effects and interaction. This was the result of the main time effect

Answer (score 2):

It's likely you've done something wrong in the code, however, questions about coding are off-topic here.

F = 0.000 is an indication that F < 0.0005 and was rounded down.  This is *possible* but it indicates that your groups had almost identical means. Perhaps you have defined your groups incorrectly.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "something wrong in the code". I've been using SPSS. The groups' means are 2.73 and 2.79, so maybe it is actually possible?

Comment: OK, if the means are that close, then the F could be that low. But that would mean that your hypothesis was way off base.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not too happy about that. Thanks for the help!